# XslCompiledTransform cant transform with XmlTestReader created from string

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a problem with XslCompiledTransform class.
If I tried to run this code:

```
string pathToXsltFile, pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile;
XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(pathToFile);
myXslTransform.Load(reader, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
myXslTransform.Transform(pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile);
```

It works fine.
But if I want to create XmlTextReader from a string (text):

```
MemoryStream mStrm = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(mStrm);
mStrm.Position = 0;
```

And try to run:

```
myXslTransform.Load(xmlReader, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
myXslTransform.Transform(pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile);
```

I get a Exception:

```
"this operation is not supported for a relative uri"
```

For some reasons I don't want to create temporaty file and create XmlTextReader from path to this file.

**Edit**:

Full exception message:

```
"An error occurred while loading document ''.
See InnerException for a complete description of the error."
```

InnerException.Message:

```
"This operation is not supported for a relative URI."
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase)
at <xsl:template match=\"gmgml:FeatureCollection\">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
at <xsl:apply-templates>(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator )
at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(XmlReader contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, Stream results)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(String inputUri, String resultsFile)
at MyNamespace.ApplyXslTransformation1(String input, String output, String xsltFileName)
```

the statement causing the exception:

```
myXslTransform.Transform(pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile);
```

About the document function I will have to ask tommorrow. I've get the xslt file from the other person.

When I've created the XmlTextReader file from the path to the xslt file everytning was fine. I've also try to use:

```
myXslTransform.Load(pathToXsltFile, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
myXslTransform.Transform(pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile);
```

And it was also fine.

Now i get the encrypted xslt. I've decrypt it and I want to create XmlTextReader from the decrypted string. Besause of the security reason i don't wont to create temporaty xslt decrypted file.

Comment: in which line you get the exception? is pathToInputFile relative path?

Comment: Please show us the exact details like the full exception message, the statement causing the exception, the stack trace and tell us whether the stylesheet code tries to resolve relative URLs (does the stylesheet code use the `document` function?).

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to see the XSLT and any calls to the `document` function it does. In general you need to be aware that [the `document` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) has a second argument that can serve as a base URI to resolve URIs resulting from the first argument. Without the second argument being passed in as in e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="document('foo.xml')"/>` the stylesheet code itself provides the base URI. If you load the stylesheet code from a string that mechanism might not resolve URIs the same way as it happens with a stylesheet loaded from the file system or a HTTP URI. The solution to that problem depends on the location of the resource you want to load and how that relates to the main input file. If you want to load `foo.xml` from the same location as the main input document then doing `document('foo.xml', /)` instead of `document('foo.xml')` should work.

Comment: I've asked for another xslt file. Without using document fucnction. Now it works. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by your manual setting of the memory stream's position to 0; you're confusing the XmlTextReader.

I tried the above and it works fine for me when I comment that line out.

Is there a particular reason you are setting it to 0?

Comment: I comment that line and I have the same exception:
{"An error occurred while loading document ''. See InnerException for a complete description of the error."}
Inner exception:
"This operation is not supported for a relative URI."

Comment: OK, then we'll need some more info as Martin Honnen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question is about using XslCompiledTransform in a .Net Core application, I found the answer to "This operation is not supported for a relative URI." at the site https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31390

The relevant answer (by vcsjones commented on Jul 26, 2018) is:

"I believe you are running in to a known compatibility change. .NET Core does not allow resolving external URIs for XML by default and is documented here.

As the documentation says, the old behavior can be restored, if you so choose, by putting

AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);
In your application. Try placing that at the top of your example program."

When I added

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);
```

as the top line of

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

in startup, the error "This operation is not supported for a relative URI" went away.  At that moment, a new error occurred calling Load with a XmlReader relating to finding the other files referenced by the XSL file.  When I then instead passed the file path to the xsl in Load, it all worked as expected.

```
var resolver = new XmlUrlResolver {Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials};
var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(XslPath, new XsltSettings(true, true), resolver);

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
using (var results = new StringWriter())
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(results, settings))
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(document)))
    {
        transform.Transform(reader, writer);
    }

    return results.ToString();
}
```

I add this in hope helps someone else trying to debug why XslCompiledTransform thows "This operation is not supported for a relative URI." in .net core.